# Pagination Into List

Tags: sencha-touch

How To Add Pagination Into List of records in sencha touch ?

help please ?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlft2.jpg ı want pagination as this picture

Answer (score 1):

I've never used paging on the list before. But I think you could see Ext.plugins.ListPagingPlugin sample for the reference :
[List Paging](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/pullrefresh/)

Comment: Thanks Yagi.I am looking this example :)

Comment: Hey, i couldn find the source code for this. Can you please help me.

Comment: @Khush It should be included in the "examples" folder of your downloaded sencha touch files :)